# Why is "tomorrow" displayed as the "Date Modified"?

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, filesystem, metadata

This is a bizarre situation-on my MacBook Pro (2017, High Sierra 10.13.5), when I opened a folder on the Finder, the `Date Modified` column for the files in a folder displays "Tomorrow at 2:34AM" and `Date Created` as "Today at 10:35PM" (see the image)--What could have caused this?[image] I am hoping this is not a sign of my laptop malfunctioning or having been hacked. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get that all the time when I download a file from Europe when the time zone differences are not corrected. Dates can be set far in the past and far in the future with simple commands like `touch` and the finder just reports the metadata / date stored in the files in question.

No real mystery or worry unless you are in some way trusting a file’s date for processing or record keeping. In that case, you’ll need to audit for the correct times and catch things that show up with non-sensical dates or dates off from the current time by some deviation you set.

Comment: Smart! Never would of thought of that.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Even though the folder was sent locally, the files might have been created elsewhere in a different time zone. It happened once before and I thought it was a glitch, but the second time got me alarmed. Thanks for clearing it up!